# How to calculate exactly the proper textwidth to get a pregiven wrapping?

Tags: width, wrap

I have a text written with 12pt letters. I would like to use 10pt letters with shorter textwidth but the same wrapping. How to calculate the width? It is possible to force LaTeX to do the same wrapping?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can't, at least if the document uses optical fonts (like Computer Modern): an `m` at 12pt size is not necessarily 20% wider than the same letter at 10pt size. You may use `\mag=0.83333` at the start of your document, with no guarantee.

Comment: Is this for a very large (multi-page) document, or just a short piece of text?

Comment: Perhaps you would be better to keep the TeX unchanged and just scale the entire document by a factor 10/12 either using \mag or simply scaling the final pdf

Comment: Even with non-optical fonts, it won't necessarily work. (It certainly won't work if you used `microtype` with various options, for example.)

Comment: This is a book with 200 pages.